# iOS FaceBook ingegration, Feeds dialog shows blank the first time

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Im using the latest FaceBook SDK for iOS, everything works fine except the first time I'm using the

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

the dialog shows a empty canvas, and dismisses itself, the next time i try the same call the dialog is just fine.

So to reproduce this error, I'm deleting the app from Facebook to initiate the authorization, session, login etc.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: i have had the same issue but the current SDK solves it, if you deug it i guess you will find -999 error.

Comment: I have the same issue with the latest SDK, is anybody else facing this issue?

Comment: I have also faced this same problem using FBconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face same issue like this. I have fix it by changing in FBDialog.m file

change

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
   // 102 == WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange
   if (!([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102)) {
        [self dismissWithError:error animated:YES];
    }
}
```

to

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // 102 == WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange
       if (!([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102)) {
           // -999 == "Operation could not be completed"
           if (!(([error.domain isEqualToString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"] && error.code == -999) ||
                          ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102))) {
            [self dismissWithError:error animated:YES];
        }
       }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem......